# Is it true that the Prophet had more than four wives at a time, and how could he break the rule?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad, polygamy, wives-of-the-prophet

In Islam at most four marriages are allowed. But I heard that prophet Muhammed (peace be upon him) had more than four wives at a time. Is it true? If true, then how could he break the rule?  (It's not intended to disrespect him.)

I am a Hindu. But have respect to all religion. I am sorry if it hurts anyone's sentiment. I also don't know how to write that prophet's name. So sorry again if I made any mistakes.